# python regular expression to collect files with same header

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a function that returns me a list of images that contain the same starting name. Here is a screenshot of the working directory.

[image]

```
def get_image_sequence(filepath):
    '''
    Description:
        Returns list of images contained in the same seq
    Args:
        filepath(str): Path to a frame in the sequence
    '''
    seq = []

    if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
            return []

    basename = os.path.basename(filepath).split('.')[0]
    directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)

    matcher = re.compile(r'^(?P<header>[\w\-.]*(?:[.]|[_]))*(?P<padding>\d+)(?P<tail>[.][A-Za-z]{1,4}$)')

    for file in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
        reMatch = matcher.match(file)
        if reMatch:
            print reMatch.group('header'), reMatch.group('padding'), reMatch.group('tail') 

    return seq
```

When i run the script trying to collect the images that are associated with this files sequence named **TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08.0018.jpg** i get this output right now:

```
TEST_ 0102 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0010 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0011 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0012 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0013 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0014 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0015 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0016 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0017 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_test_v08. 0028 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_test_v08. 0029 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_test_v08. 0030 .jpg
```

I was wondering if there is a way i can insert into the re, the **basename** which is TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. That way reMatch only tests True if the prefix matches for each file and then returns this:

```
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0010 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0011 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0012 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0013 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0014 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0015 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0016 .jpg
TEST_0102_000_010_fx_playblast_v08. 0017 .jpg
```

Comment: why not `if not basename in file: continue` just before your `reMatch = matcher.match(file)`? - or use `file.startswith(basename)` - or even: `if reMatch and basename in file:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
matcher = re.compile(r'^(?P<header>' + basename + ')\.(?P<padding>\d+)(?P<tail>[.][A-Za-z]{3})$')
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tpOcl4/1)

Please note that I have also modified the padding and tail regex slightly.

Comment: named group tail was `[.][A-Za-z]{1,4}`. i.e. a '.' (dot) followed by one to four characters. I changed it to `[.][A-Za-z]{3}` .  i.e. a '.' (dot) followed by exactly 3 characters. Feel free to change it back, if you need to have one to four characters as extension.